How to request user input for power automate flow
Hi Power Automate Team,
I've developed a flow activated by the MS Teams For a selected message action. Following activation, my goal is to ask for additional details from the user.

I understand this is achievable, as demonstrated by the Create a new Trello card from a message flow.

When attempting to construct a similar flow that includes requested fields, I encounter difficulties saving the flow due to these fields being mandatory.
As illustrated in the example below, I aim to prompt the user to enter the x-space-id, which is a dynamic list variable, in an MS Teams popup, similar to the Trello scenario.

The power automate docs point to creating templates but at the end it says template creation is depricated
UPDATE:

Adaptive cards are is before the dynamic list is run in the flow, and there is no way to pass the list to them.

Trello Temaplte example does not use Adaptive cards:





My guess is that, because this is a template, empty fields are allowed when creating the flow. These empty fields are then filled by the user when using/instantiating the template. However, since the creation of templates is no longer available and has been deprecated, it is now impossible for users to provide information. Great job, Microsoft!
How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Dropdown fields typically have a custom value option. When you select that you should be able to use a field from your trigger action in that custom value option. Alternatively, you can also an expression.
Below is an example
In this adaptive card I have used an Input.Text with id xspaceid.
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
                {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Provide Your Space",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "xspaceid",
            "placeholder": "x-space-id",
            "spacing": "None"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }
    ]
}

As you can see that is available to be reused in a Power Automate action. For example in the Create a Card action I can add it to the Board Id field if I switch to the custom value option in the dropdown and search for it in the Dynamic Content list.

Here is a link to the documentation, if that helps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-flow-teams-message

x-space-id is a dynamic list variable, in other words similar to Trello, a user chooses a possible x-space-id values from a list. If I follow your instructions then user will be asked to input the x-space-id manually instead.
Also, if you look at the Trello template, they don't use adaptive cards like you suggest. https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-ca/templates/details/0e9e8e425a6c4f599af2f602ccb9916f/create-a-new-trello-card-from-a-message/

In the Trello template they use a similar adaptive card. Only difference with my example is that the Text.Input is called cardName instead of x-space-id. So, the approach is actually the same. Btw, the first screenshot of your opening post is the selection for the setup of the flow, this has nothing to do with the input the flow is asking from users when the flow is already setup and running. The Trello template only works with one board which you select during setup, that's it. If you want to change it to allow selection at input I would suggest to use a Input.ChoiceSet in your adaptive card.

I see some confusion here. I'm not concerned about the Card Name—that's clear. I'm after the Board Id and Parent List Id. I want to bring your attention back to the first screenshot: how can I ask the user to input information similar to what's shown there? I know both fields are dynamic, populated by another HTTP request, and I've successfully managed to create one as well. However, I want the user to input these values to set up and run the flow when triggering the template. I guess template creation is no longer available, and this was only possible via template creation.

I can't use Input.ChoiceSet because the choices need to be populated both dynamically and statically, and as I understand, that's not possible in an adaptive card."

Yes, I understand your need to populate the choices. I just wanted to point out that this Trello template wasn't suited for your requirements, sorry for the confusion. In your case you might want to have a look at typeahead search, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/dynamic-search?tabs=desktop%2Ccsharp#dynamic-typeahead-search But this does require coding.

And if I want to replicate Trello, how is it possible?

Also:


Adaptive cards is first in the flow and dynamic flow is not available at that point. Thus you cannot pass the it


Trello Temaple example does not use Adaptive cards:


